# Autofill using Javascript got remove when tap on text input, how to solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events

I don't know about Javascript but I write a code to autofill form in this https://www.adidas.com/us/delivery site. That successfully fills the form,
but when I tap on text input all text input fields go blank automatically.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOo7K.gif) that strange behaviour Gif.

But I want that fields to remain fill, when I tap on that.

Here's the Javascript that I've used:

```
document.getElementsByName('shippingAddress.firstName')[0].value = 'Aafaq'; 
document.getElementsByName('shippingAddress.lastName')[0].value = 'Ahmed'; 
document.getElementsByName('shippingAddress.address1')[0].value = '553  Shinn Street'; 
document.getElementsByName('shippingAddress.city')[0].value = 'New York'; 
document.getElementsByName('shippingAddress.zipcode')[0].value = '10021'; 
document.getElementsByName('shippingAddress.phoneNumber')[0].value = '+1-202-555-0123'; 
document.getElementsByName('shippingAddress.emailAddress')[0].value = 'anymail@gmail.com';
```

I have to use this code with Swift iOS, can anyone tell me how I can solve this issue, and what is happening under the hood?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Javascript != Java

Comment: Please remove the java tag. Java doesn't have anything to do with Javascript.

Comment: It could be likely that this is to prevent bots from filling in these forms by computationally storing any value entered by the user (perhaps you should dispatch a `change` or `input` event to each as its likely they are listening for that as it only triggers on user input, not when programmatically changing value: `document.getElementsByName('shippingAddress.firstName')[0].dispatchEvent( new Event( 'change')`).

Comment: Hi @somethinghere thanks for giving me some new direction, can you write some code that I can test directly to the chrome by pasting, because I don't know JavaScript

Comment: I have to use it with swift.

Comment: The code is in the comments, with one example. Just add that dispatchEvent after changing the value of the input. I do not know what you'd need `swift` for here - its just javascript you paste in your browser. Swift is a programming language for apps on iPhone...

Comment: I am swift programmer, I have to make autofill in swift using `WKWebView` , there is function in `WKWebView` that evaluates javascript and allow user to make changes in website. I have to pass this javascript over there, but the site behaviour is strange.

Comment: After changing value of text input, I've change value but it does not work for me.
I would be grateful to you if you help me out, I am trying a lot from 2 days but to no avail.